# Load nested links via Java with jsoup

Tags: java, html, web-crawler, jsoup

I am working on crawler via jsoup. I want to display link(s) of categories from asian e-shop https://world.taobao.com/. My code is able find all link on the page thanks to:

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
System.out.println("Total results: " + links.size());
```

But not all of them. I need to show only links for categories, which are nested in many `<div>` tags.

[image: anchor]

Here is my code:

```
package jsoup;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Crawler {  

public static final String CLS_NAME = "Crawler";

    public static final String URL_SOURCE = "https://world.taobao.com/";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        // load Document
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL_SOURCE).get();

        // select only <a> tag with "href" attribute  
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        System.out.println("Total results: " + links.size());

        for (Element url: links){
            System.out.println(String.format("* [%s] : %s ", url.text(), url.attr("abs:href")));

        }
    }
}
```

Could you please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with your code.

The particular site generates parts of its content using JavaScript. As Jsoup is able to get only static parts of the site, so you won't be able to crawl it this easily.

You can still use tools such as [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org) for that, as they actually execute JavaScript code inside the browser.

Comment: Thank you Alexey, It was an answer which I feared :)

Comment: And I want to ask if it's possible to extract positive and negative comments on certain product over jsoup?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDTMM.png

Comment: It's possible to extract with JSoup anything that's rendered on the page on server side, and not by JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, thank you for answer :) I will try to chcek json for parsing comments.